# How do I avoid the popup box when closing a VirtualBox VM?

Tags: virtualbox

How do I avoid the popup box when closing a VirtualBox VM? It asks me if I want to save the state, send the shutdown signal or power off the VM.

For any given VM, my choice will almost always be the same. Ideally, this would be something I could configure in the VM settings, but it's not.

I know there's a command line thing I can do, but for this situation, I just want to hit "close" and have it save its state.

Answer (score 2):

Believe it!  It appears the developers for VBox haven't seen the necessity to implement this.  You might want to file a feature request with the project or get involved and see if you can add it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This is critical for power management initiated shutdown.  I was hoping there was a way for the host OS shutdown sequence to trigger safe shutdown of all VMs in VirtualBox.  as of Jan 2012 there appears to be no way to set the default method for VM shutdown.  I will try triggering the host OS to hybernate but that is funky and a poor work-around.

Answer (score 1):

In the interim, you could create an [AutoHotkey Script](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or macro to automatically make the choice for you whenever the window appears. AutoHotkey distributes a script recorder, so you can record yourself doing the action once and it will write the code for you.